# Is it possible to use lambda to execute an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that finds a keyword in an array (clues) and returns its position, I am trying to take this result and execute it as a puts command. This search is necessary as I will not always know 'Software includes' position in the array

My code below just simple outputs "clues[2]" but I want to actually execute puts clues[2] as though I had typed it in so my output would be "Software included".

Is there a way to make this workable?

```
clues = Array.new 
clues << 'Power supply type' 
clues << 'Slots'
clues << 'Software included'

Var100 = clues.rindex('Software included')
Var101 = "clues[#{Var100}]" 

command_store = Array.new
command_store << lambda {puts "clues[#{Var101}]" }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I am trying to output puts "clues[#{Var101}]" as a command and not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're complicating things too much. For example, your `puts` command in a lambda is equivalent to this:

```
puts "clues[clues[2]]"
```

With a little debug printing you'll be able to make it work. Here's what I think you want to get:

```
clues = ['Power supply type', 'Slots', 'Software included']

command_store = []
command_store << lambda { 
  idx = clues.rindex('Software included')
  puts clues[idx] 
}
command_store.each(&:call) # call every lambda in the array
# >> Software included
```

Although this exact code doesn't make any sense to me (who gets value's index only to use that index to print the value), I understand that it may be an over-simplified example.

### Hints:

- Don't start variable names with a capital letter;
- Try to make sensible names for variables. It'll make your life easier later;
- Prefer `[]` to `Array.new` at all times.